# Неубрано или не убрано?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Слитно или раздельно? В доме не()убрано.

Answer (score 2):

***В доме не убрано. (В доме неубрано.)***

Вариант *не убрано* — более частотный, но *неубрано* тоже встречается в текстах:

...он скажет: «Ты будешь дорогим гостем… как-нибудь в другой раз», аргументируя это тем, что **дома у него неубрано** [Надежда Навроцкая.2010]

― Иначе кто из нее тогда вырастет? Куда-то она уехала на несколько дней и, вернувшись, устроила скандал, что **дома всё неубрано.**  [Михаил Шишкин. Письмовник (2009) // «Знамя», 2010]

Можно предположить такие варианты: *в комнате  убрано* (чистота и порядок), *не убрано* (не успели убрать, пока еще нет порядка),  *неубрано* (грязь и беспорядок).

― Да там… э… **неубрано совсем**, ― смутилась бабка, ― барахло всякое старушечье...[Влада Валеева. Скорая помощь (2002)]

Это предикативные наречия в безличном предложении.

Из словаря: **НЕУБРАННЫЙ**,  1. Такой, который не убран, не приведён в порядок. Н-ая посуда. Н-ая голова. Н-ая постель.

Можно предположить, что краткая форма в данном случае пишется с одной буквой Н

Comment: *Очень странно.*

Comment: А что странно? Отрицания нет, но есть утверждение (в доме  беспорядок).

Comment: А я думал, что такого наречия нету...

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что такое наречие можно найти в словарях,  но оно встречается в  современных текстах, и для этого есть основания, а именно утвердительное значение слова. Что касается словарей, то они часто отстают от практики и фиксируют только те формы, которые  уже достаточно освоены.

Comment: И всё-таки мне оно не очень нравится. Эдакое наречие по действию...

Answer (score 0):

Раздельно. Нет наречия "неубрано".